# Turn widget's focus on and off based on mouse enter/leave event

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm3

I want to turn on `Gtk::SpinButton` entry focus when mouse pointer enters this widget and then turn it off again when the pointer leaves.

The signal event doesn't seem to respond while the window is still running. But the `std::cout` outputs are printed after I close the window.

How do I implement my expected widget behavior?

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

class SpinButtonExample : public Gtk::Window {
    Gtk::Grid                     grid;
    Gtk::Label                    label;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Adjustment> adjustment;
    Gtk::SpinButton               spinbutton;

public:
    SpinButtonExample();
    bool on_enter_notify_event(GdkEventCrossing *);
    bool on_leave_notify_event(GdkEventCrossing *);
};

SpinButtonExample::SpinButtonExample()
    : label     ("Hi")
    , adjustment(Gtk::Adjustment::create(0, 0, 10))
    , spinbutton(adjustment)
{
    add_events(Gdk::ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK);
    add_events(Gdk::LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK);

    spinbutton.signal_enter_notify_event().connect(
                sigc::mem_fun(*this, &SpinButtonExample::on_enter_notify_event));
    spinbutton.signal_leave_notify_event().connect(
                sigc::mem_fun(*this, &SpinButtonExample::on_leave_notify_event));

    grid.set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    grid.set_column_homogeneous(true);
    grid.set_margin_start(10);
    grid.set_margin_end(10);
    grid.set_margin_top(10);
    grid.set_margin_bottom(10);
    grid.add(label);
    grid.add(spinbutton);

    add(grid);

    show_all();
}

bool
SpinButtonExample::on_enter_notify_event(GdkEventCrossing *event)
{
    if (event->type == GDK_SCROLL) {
        std::cout << "Mouse entered\n";
        spinbutton.set_can_focus();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool
SpinButtonExample::on_leave_notify_event(GdkEventCrossing *event)
{
    if (event->type == GDK_LEAVE_NOTIFY) {
        std::cout << "Mouse left\n";
        spinbutton.set_can_focus(false);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int
main()
{
    auto application = Gtk::Application::create("test.focus.spinbutton");

    SpinButtonExample test;

    return application->run(test);
}
```

Comment: What if you put `std::endl` in your `cout`s? i.e. is it just `cout` not flushing that makes you think the events are being delayed until the end of the process.

Comment: and if you want to turn on focusability on entry, why are you checking `if (event->type == GDK_SCROLL)`? pointer entry and scrolling are different things, obviously. but you shouldn't need to bother checking either, since getting the signal means the event has that type, otherwise why would the signals be named for specific types of events...?

Comment: Thanks @underscore_d `std::endl` worked. But leave notify is not turning off my widget focus

Comment: What do you mean? Does it not turn off _focusability_? and/or does it leave the widget _focussed_?

Comment: Leaves the widget focussed

Comment: Try returning focus to some other 'default' widget first, then.

Comment: Added a button, set it as default, and set default false for SpinButton... Still same behavior

Comment: Thanks @underscore_d for *focus to some other 'default' widget first* I missed your hint! That worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge THANKS to underscore_d's comments above.

The answer to this is to direct our focus to another widget when mouse pointer leaves `Gtk::SpinButton` widget and for enter event, grab the focus back.

Just turning on and off with `set_can_focus()` won't work.

Below is the corrected solution:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

class SpinButtonExample : public Gtk::Window {
    Gtk::Grid                     grid;
    Gtk::Label                    label;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Adjustment> adjustment;
    Gtk::SpinButton               spinbutton;
    Gtk::Button                   button;

public:
    SpinButtonExample();
    bool on_enter_notify_event(GdkEventCrossing *);
    bool on_leave_notify_event(GdkEventCrossing *);
};

SpinButtonExample::SpinButtonExample()
    : label     ("Hi")
    , adjustment(Gtk::Adjustment::create(0, 0, 10))
    , spinbutton(adjustment)
    , button    ("Default")
{
    add_events(Gdk::ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK);
    add_events(Gdk::LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK);

    button.set_margin_start(10);
    button.set_can_default();
    button.grab_focus();

    spinbutton.set_can_default(false);
    spinbutton.signal_enter_notify_event().connect(
                sigc::mem_fun(*this, &SpinButtonExample::on_enter_notify_event));
    spinbutton.signal_leave_notify_event().connect(
                sigc::mem_fun(*this, &SpinButtonExample::on_leave_notify_event));

    grid.set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    grid.set_column_homogeneous(true);
    grid.set_margin_start(10);
    grid.set_margin_end(10);
    grid.set_margin_top(10);
    grid.set_margin_bottom(10);
    grid.add(label);
    grid.add(spinbutton);
    grid.add(button);

    add(grid);

    show_all();
}

bool
SpinButtonExample::on_enter_notify_event(GdkEventCrossing *event)
{
    if (event->type == GDK_ENTER_NOTIFY) {
        std::cout << "Mouse entered" << std::endl;
        spinbutton.grab_focus();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool
SpinButtonExample::on_leave_notify_event(GdkEventCrossing *event)
{
    if (event->type == GDK_LEAVE_NOTIFY) {
        std::cout << "Mouse left" << std::endl;
        button.grab_focus();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int
main()
{
    auto application = Gtk::Application::create("test.focus.spinbutton");

    SpinButtonExample test;

    return application->run(test);
}
```